# AWS DynamoDB deleteTable not working when called from NodeJs 8.10 Lambda Function

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

As part of a Lambda training effort, I am attempting to write a simple application that triggers a Lambda function via API Gateway. That Lambda function then connects to DynamoDB via the AWS SDK and attempts to delete an existing table.

The Lambda function fires when I perform a `POST` against the API Gateway endpoint. I get a response back as `{}`, which means that `result` was never re-assigned beyond the initialized value. As far as I can tell the `deleteTable` method never fires. I never see either the `console.log()` or the `console.error()`, which exist inside the body of the callback.

Please find details below:

### Setup

#### Lambda Function

- Language: Node.Js 8.10
- Triggers: API Gateway `POST` endpoint
- Execution Role Rights:

  - Basic Microservice Template (Note: I've also attempting giving it explicit DynamoDB Full Access, and even Full Administrator; this didn't help anything.

Here's the code. I had something a lot more involved but trimmed it down to this when I couldn't get the delete to work:

```
exports.handler = async (event) => {
    var aws = require('aws-sdk');
    var dynamodb = new aws.DynamoDB();
    
    var params = {
        TableName: "StudyGuideSections"
    };
    
    var result = {};
    
    dynamodb.deleteTable(params, function(err, data) {
        console.log('Entering deleteTable callback...');
        
       if (err) {
           console.log(err, err.stack);
       } else {
           console.log(data);
           
           result = data;
       }
    });
    
    return {
        statusCode: 200,
        "headers": {
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(result)
    };
};
```

#### API Gateway

- Authorization: None
- Method: POST

#### Client-Side

- Postman (For testing)
- Simple web application executing `$.post`

I've looked at the *CloudWatch* and *X-Ray* logs and I don't ever see errors, nor do I see the console.log() attempts from inside the body of the `deleteTable()` call.

I'm all but pulling my hair out at this point as it has put a blocker on my training. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: For further clarification, I can change the return value's body to be something like "Hello World!" and I get that back as the response. Additionally, I can put a `console.log('Attempting to delete table...")` right before the `deleteTable` call; when I do that, I see it in CloudWatch. I just never see the logs from inside the `deleteTable` method.

Comment: Do you see any logs at all? Is your lambda even being called by the GW?

Comment: Yes, I see logs in CloudWatch. The logs simply show the start and end of the call. If I put a console.log before the deleteTable, I see the console.log message in CloudWatch. If I change the result body to be something like "Hello World!", I see that message in the Response from Postman. The function fires, it just never calls deleteTable for some reason.

Comment: Hmm you seem to be missing `=>` after the function call. This is what I mean : `dynamodb.deleteTable(params, function(err, data) =>`

Comment: Hmmm...I don't think you can use that syntax. I would have to do this ```dynamodb.deleteTable(params, (err, data) => {```, which I just tried and it doesn't make a difference.

Comment: Fair enough, my bad

Comment: No worries! Thanks anyway!

Comment: Was on top of my head. If the problem persists tomorrow (as i have just finished work), I will help you out with debugging. Best of luck!

Comment: Cool. Thanks. If I figure it out before then, I'll definitely respond back with the answer for anyone else who might come across this issue.

Comment: in my case I have nested functions where the last child is a call to dynamoDB:  `await conection.update(params).promise()` ... but I forgot to put **await** in every parent function, without this, node stops executing the function before the promise returns. it looks like the call it's never made, Nevertheless it's aborted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured this out. Because I was utilizing Node.js 8.10, I needed to use the *Promise* structure instead of the *Callback* structure.

**Edit:**

As Kalev mentioned, the fact that I'm using an `async` function for the handler is what necessitated the use of the `await` and `.promise()` and not the fact that I was using Node.js 8.10, which still supports the callback structure.

For example, instead of what I was originally attempting, I needed to do something more like this:

```
var aws = require('aws-sdk');

exports.handler = async (event) => {
    var ddb = new aws.DynamoDB();

    aws.config.update({
      region: "us-east-1"
    });

    var params = {
        TableName: "StudyGuideSections"
    };

    var result = {}

    try
    {
        result = await ddb.deleteTable(params).promise();
    }
    catch(ex) {
        result = ex;
    }

    return {
        statusCode: 200,
        "headers": {
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(result)
    };
};
```

Make special note of the `result = await ddb.deleteTable(params).promise();` as that's the part that I was messing up.

Comment: It is not the use of callbacks in node 8.10 per se, but instead the combination of callbacks and promises. if instead of an `async` functions (which is essentially syntactic sugar for promises) your function handler was of the traditional callback form (supported in 8.10), it would work fine.
Also, there's a configuration that ensures the lambda does not terminate until all callbacks have been resolved, which might have worked as well.